# How to make Owl Carousel keyboard accessible

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

According to the [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/), in order for a website to be considered accessible, you should be able to use a keyboard for all functionality of the content:

> All functionality of the content is operable through a keyboard
>   interface

I'm using Owl Carousel 2, and added arrows and linked them like so:

```
$('.carousel-left-arrow').click(function () {
        owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
    });
```

But those arrows are not accessible using the keyboard, only the mouse.
How can I make them accessible?

Answer (score 1):

First, in order for a `div` to be accessible by keyboard, you need to add the `tabindex` attribute to it. For example:

```
    <div class="carousel-arrow carousel-right-arrow" tabindex="0" >
```

Then in your script, you can use jQuery to make pressing Enter on the div trigger the same event as a mouse click:

```
$('.carousel-arrow').keypress(function (e) {
    if(e.which === 13)
    {
        this.click();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Better still, just use BUTTON and style it as you want - BUTTONs are fully keyboard accessible right out of the box.

Comment: @BrendanMcK Thank you for this better solution. Only downside is the style.

Comment: Definitely use a `<button>`, which supports both the *Enter* key and the *Space* key, so make sure to also listen for character 32. As for styling, a `<button>` can be styled just like any other element so that is never a reason not to use it.